# Multi-Column Layouts with Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I want to create a site with different column-layouts depending on the current route.

I basically achieved this by calling for every route in the appropriate layout controller with the corresponding layout in advance.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <div class="container">
        {{outlet}}
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="twocolumns">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="span8">
        {{outlet main}}
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        {{outlet sidebar}}
    </div>
  </div>


</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="home">
    <h1>Home</h1>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="sidebar">
    <h1>Sidebar</h1>
</script>


  home: Ember.Route.extend({
    route: '/',
    connectOutlets: function(router, event) {
        router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('twocolumns');
        router.get('twocolumnsController').connectOutlet('main', 'home');
        router.get('twocolumnsController').connectOutlet('sidebar', 'sidebar');
    }
  }),
```

Is there a better approach e.g. extending Route class with the different layouts ?

Comment: I'm not clear enough on the problem or your current solution to be helpful. Perhaps you could post a JS Fiddle illustrating it?